# cancel download using an reactive observable

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I've created this method in order to create `Observable`'s from events. I'm trying to download a file, and update a progress bar:

```
private void BuildObservables(WebClient webClient)
{
    Observable.FromEventPattern<AsyncCompletedEventHandler, AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(h => webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += h, h => webClient.DownloadFileCompleted -= h)
        .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
        .Subscribe(
            a =>
            {
                this.WizardViewModel.PageCompleted()
            },
        );

    Observable.FromEventPattern<DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs>(h => webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += h, h => webClient.DownloadProgressChanged -= h)
        .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
        .Subscribe(
            a =>
            {
                this.progressEdit.Position = a.ProgressPercentage;
                progressEdit.Update();
            }
        );
}
```

However, when I download is started I'd like to provide a User button in order to cancel the download process.

How could I add this cancelation based on this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebClient` has a `CancelAsync` method, that may do the job.

As far as Rx goes, you can't cancel the download, but you can dispose of the subscription, which effectively means ignoring future updates:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var dummyDownloadPath = @"C:\temp\temp.txt";
    var disposable = BuildObservables(webClient);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(@"http://google.com"), dummyDownloadPath);
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    disposable.Dispose();
}
private IDisposable BuildObservables(WebClient webClient)
{
    var downloadSubscription = Observable.FromEventPattern<AsyncCompletedEventHandler, AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(
        h => webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += h, 
        h => webClient.DownloadFileCompleted -= h
    )
        .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
        .Subscribe(
            a =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Download completed.");
//              this.WizardViewModel.PageCompleted()
            }
        );

    var progressSubscription = Observable.FromEventPattern<DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs>(
            h => webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += h, 
            h => webClient.DownloadProgressChanged -= h
        )
        .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
        .Subscribe(
            a =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Download Percent complete:" + a.ProgressPercentage);
                //              this.progressEdit.Position = a.ProgressPercentage;
                //              progressEdit.Update();
            }
        );
        return new CompositeDisposable(downloadSubscription, progressSubscription);
}
```

Comment: So, as far I've been able to figure out you suggest me to perform first: `webClient.CancelAsync()` and then dispose the observable using `disposable.Dispose()`, doesn't it?